# using a access data base to save data from a web site (nickname,pass,answers,replies,ect)

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

is it possivel to connect a web site do a access data base? because I'm using a access data base on visual basic and I want to make 1 db do all apps. is it possivel? if it is does any one have any code or examples so share?

ps: this is for a school project so please don't use very professional terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use odbc and a library to connect via that odbc connection to the database.

1. ODBC PHP Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php
2. steps to
   create an odbc connection:
   http://www.ehow.com/how_4642566_setup-odbc-database-connection.html

a quick google returned this php example:
http://www.web-max.ca/PHP/odbc_1.php

Comment: i can use that to conect my website to the db? because i alredy know how to insert,delete and edite data on the db using vb2010 , i just want to know if it is possivel to do the same using a site

Comment: im sorry if im beeing to confuse with my question

Comment: yes, read the 3 links. the first one outlines how to use the ODBC Library in php to connect to an odbc connection. 2nd shows how to create an odbc connection and 3rd is a example of both in conjunction to connect to a database.

Comment: yes - give you using vb.net, then asp.net + vb.net would allow your code to function much the same as now. The only real requirement is that you web hosting has the ACE/JET database engine installed and is supported on that platform. This thus means you have to use windows hosting. However you really gain VERY little by using a access database as opposed to say SQL server with that web site. You not using any access features, forms etc., but only a data store. This means your application really don't care if you use SQL server, or access - the code will be much the same.